# Pictures in the like box missing

Tags: facebook-likebox

I don't know if it's a temporary bug or a setting change but, as of today, the pictures I post on the page I manage are no more reproduced in the Like box (only the text is shown). 
I get the same result when trying from the developers page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Does any of you experience the same problem? For sure it's a hard blow to my like box visibility :-((

Comment: I was able to confirm that certain pages are still displaying pictures in their like box streams (although not all).  Could be an intermittent Facebook social plugins issue.  To be safe, have you confirmed your app (if you have one) is compliant with all migrations?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not have an app: I simply implemented the likebox code on my homepage (I am working on PC). Yesterday the pictures were displayed, today they are not. I notice that there was a "July 2013 migration": where can I learn more about it?

Comment: Can you post the social plugin code you're using?

Comment: <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/fumettoalfemminile" data-width="552" data-height="485" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-header="false"></div>

Comment: the data-href attribute has an absolute URL: "http:// www .facebook .com/ fumettoalfemminile" (had to add the spaces to show the correct syntax)

Comment: Looks like some of the images in your feed are showing, while others are not.  Mainly they show when sharing a link (possibly to og:image).  This looks like a possible Facebook issue, although I'd suggest taking a look here: [FB Devs Roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/).  Per their changes: "Social plugins will require an absolute URL in the 'href' parameter Social plugins, such as the Like Box and Like Button, will require an absolute URL in the 'href' parameter." Whereas the code you posted is missing the `https://`

Comment: thanks. I did not notice that some of the images are showing (curious and curiouser!!). I modified the URL, but nothing changed: I really hope this is just a temp issue, because I could not find any help in the link you send. thanks again anyway.

Comment: We have this problem, too, but find that Instagram pictures shared on FB always display OK in Likebox - presumably the styling is different for them?

Answer (score 0):

Try to post a picture again. Image width is 398px or less, you can see this!

Answer (score 0):

This is a Facebook issue. The missing images are actually there, but the result of the css styling is that they have height and width of 0px. It only affects some images and it seems it is images posted after a certain date. (The images that are visible are styled with different classes.)

I have just filed a bug report (as it affected a site I manage) here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/723454951004368

For anyone who wants the technical details, here they are:

> When using the Like Box Social Plugin some images (seemingly those posted after a specific, recent date) are not displaying in the stream. (Any descriptive text posted with the image *is* being displayed.)
>
> The is a css issue. The image is there in the html, but the result of the css styling is that it has a height and width of 0px.
>
> The img element itself is styled with a width of 100% (i.e. 100% of its containing element) (from the 'img' class) and absolute positioning (from the '_46-i' class); its containing div element also has width of 100% ('photoWrap' class) and relative positioning ('_46-h' class); and 'a' element containing all of this floats left ('photoRedesignAspect').
>
> As the 'a' is floating, it is only as wide as it needs to be for the elements it contains. As the img element has absolute positioning, it is not part of the document flow and so the 'a' element has a width of 0. The div, then, has a width of 100% of this 0, which is 0; and the img itself then has a width of 100% of this 0, which is again 0.
>
> Quite logical really!
>
> If the img element is give static positioning rather than absolute then this problem is resolved.

OF course, this simple change needs to be made by Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I am also having this issue on my site, http://www.face-painting-fun.com/

It is extremely irritating and I also have let FB know about the bug, but so far (no action that I have been aware of, to respond or fix the bug), has been taken.

Additionally I have found that if the images are square or close to square they display OK...